# How to log stream data to file with socat, ncat

Tags: netcat, socat

I am learning about socat and ncat. I want to log stream data to a file. With ncat, I can do like below:

ncat <some params> --output save_file.txt

The first question is how can I do same thing with socat?

Secondly, I only want to save the data of a direction, not both, but still want the stream is bidirectional. How can I do that?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

New Socat versions provide options -r and -R to log stream data of each direction to files.